# How to caprure keyevents of child widgets in QT

Tags: qt, events

I have created the Ui screen named `HomeScreen.ui` in Qt. This screen have no of different widget like `QPushButton`, `QLabel` etc. I want change the default navigation, for that I was trying to capture the `keyEvents` using `keyPressedEvent` function

```
void HomeScreen::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event )
{
    int keyCode = event->key();
    qDebug() << keyCode;
}
```

but this is captuting event only when the focus is on homescreen, if the focus is on any child widget like push button `keyPressEvent` is not getting called. I want to capture event on child widgets so that i can write the navigation for them.

Can anybody tell me how to do that?

Comment: what do you mean by "changing the default navigation"? Do you have a form and you want the user to be able to navigate in it with the arrow keys?

Comment: @Uflex thanks forthe reply ....yes..actually i have to change the navigation between the widgets in the form according to requirement ...I have fixed the above mentioned issue by using 'ignoreEvent' in the child widget 'keyPressEvent' function